# Wordpress custom taxonomy subcategory template

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create specific templates based on custom taxonomy subcategory slugs.
Custom taxonomy is registered with CPT UI plugin.

An example explaining the problem:

Registered custom taxonomy: Fruits

Fruits has a category: Apples

Apples has a subcategories with slugs: red-apple, green-apple, yellow-apple

My goal is to use specific template for each subcategory: red-apple, green-apple and yellow-apple

What I have tried so far:

1. I created a files such as `taxonomy-fruits-red-apple.php, taxonomy-apples-red-apple.php` etc - none worked.
2. Used the following code:

```
    function wpd_subcategory_template( $template ) {
    $cat = get_queried_object();
    if ( isset( $cat ) && $cat->category_parent ) {
        $template = locate_template( 'my-template.php' );
    }
    
return $template;
}
add_filter( 'category_template', 'wpd_subcategory_template' );
```

None of these methods worked.

Any ideas?

Thx in advance!